# Auto-increment composite key that is partitioned by a foreign key in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have a table with a composite key of `Comment_Id` and `Prod_Id`. `Prod_Id` is the FK to another table, and I'd like to auto-increment the `Comment_Id`, but I want it to be partitioned by `Prod_Id`, so it should restart the count with every new `Prod_Id`.

Similar to this table:

[Table Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWp51.png)

Currently, I have this in my `DbContext` file:

```
builder.Entity<Comments>()
       .HasKey(x => new { x.CommentId, x.ProdId });
builder.Entity<Comments>()
       .Property(p => p.CommentId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

This doesn't work, since it won't reset the auto-increment with every `Prod_Id`.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked quite a few times. The answer is always: there's no built-in method. Do it in application code, or (better) never mind generated surrogate key values. They are (and should be) meaningless.